# Scroll position is reset on reloadData when calculating dynamic header size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a big `UIcollectionView` with some custom logic, and in its header I have another `UICollectionView` with scroll direction set to horizontal. Beside that, I have other labels inside that header view. I get the dynamic height of the header like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: section)
    let headerView = self.collectionView(collectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, at: indexPath)
    
    let desiredWidth = collectionView.frame.width > 0 ? collectionView.frame.width : UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    return headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: desiredWidth, height: UIView.layoutFittingExpandedSize.height),
                                                      withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, // Width is fixed
                                                      verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel) // Height can be as large as needed
}
```

The height is calculated correctly, but if I scroll the horizontal collectionView and then from somewhere in the code reloadData is called, its scroll position is reseted.
I know this is happening because of `let headerView = self.collectionView(collectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, at: indexPath)` this line, but is there any way to have dynamic header height and the scroll not to be reseted?

Comment: Have you tried setting a variable with the collection view's current offset position each time it scrolls (which can be captured in the scroll view delegate methods)?  You could do that a minimum and then set the content's offset position when the header view is returned, which I imagine you'd set in the supplementary view method, not the layout method, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to keep an instance of the headerView when dequeued and then re-use it when calculating the height of the header.

```
if let headerView = self.headerView {
   return headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(
                    CGSize(width: desiredWidth, height: UIView.layoutFittingExpandedSize.height),
                    withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, // Width is fixed
                    verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel) // Height can be as large as needed
}
            
return CGSize(width: desiredWidth, height: 1)
```